# How to draw ARFaceGeometry using OpenGLES?

Tags: ios, arkit, iphone-x, face-id

I am drawing ARFaceGeometry using OpenGLES on my iPhoneX, I draw GL_POINTS and the points tracking my face, but it seems not the correct result, anyone please help me to find where is wrong?

Here is my drawing code:

```
ARFaceGeometry *faceGeometry = [[ARFaceGeometry alloc] initWithBlendShapes:self.faceAnchor.blendShapes];

GLuint vertexBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, faceGeometry.vertexCount*3*sizeof(GLfloat), faceGeometry.vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

GLuint textureCoordBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &textureCoordBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, faceGeometry.textureCoordinateCount*2*sizeof(GLfloat), faceGeometry.textureCoordinates, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

GLuint indexBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &indexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, faceGeometry.triangleCount*3*sizeof(unsigned short), faceGeometry.triangleIndices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

[self.program setUniformMatrix4fv:@"u_pMatrix" value:self.projectionMatrix.m];
[self.program setUniformMatrix4fv:@"u_vMatrix" value:self.viewMatrix.m];
[self.program setUniformMatrix4fv:@"u_mMatrix" value:(GLfloat *)self.faceAnchor.transform.columns];
[self.program setUniform1i:@"maskTexture" value:[self.texture activeUnit:1]];
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
[self.program setAttribute:@"a_vertex" size:3 stride:3*sizeof(GLfloat) offset:0];

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureCoordBuffer);
[self.program setAttribute:@"a_texture_coord" size:2 stride:2*sizeof(GLfloat) offset:0];

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, (int)faceGeometry.triangleCount*3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

[image: draw GL_POINTS]

[image: draw GL_TRIANGLES]

Comment: I've solved this question!

Comment: Great! Please post your solution as an answer so that others encountering similar issues can benefit.

Comment: @Misery Please can you share how you fixed the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found that vector_float3 has the same size and alignment with simd_float4.

So I replace

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, faceGeometry.vertexCount*3*sizeof(GLfloat), faceGeometry.vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

with

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, faceGeometry.vertexCount*4*sizeof(GLfloat), faceGeometry.vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

this fix my problem!